# Rancher cluster logging with fluentd doesn't work

Tags: fluentd, rancher

Could you plz help me?

I've set rancher cluster logger to fluentd.
(Tools -> Logging -> select fluentd and type endpoint etc then test and saved)
And fluentd stores log to minio(s3 compatible object storage).

After that, only test log of 'cluster logging enabled' or fluentd's own log(like fluentd worker started etc.) is sent to minio.

Any application logs on k8s cluster provisioned by rancher has not been stored on minio.

Rancher version is 2.3.3 and without fluentd Endpoint, any other setting values is not set.
And below is my fluentd configuration.

```
<match **>
  @type s3
  @log_level info
  aws_key_id accesskey   
  aws_sec_key secretkey  
  s3_bucket logs   
  s3_endpoint https://myminio    
  s3_region us-east-1     
  path logs/              
  force_path_style true   
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M  
  store_as json

  <buffer time>
    @type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/s3
    timekey 1m            
    timekey_wait 10s      
    timekey_use_utc true  
    chunk_limit_size 256m 
  </buffer>

  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>

<source>
  @type forward
  @id input_forward
</source>
```

Comment: I didn't recognize my cluster option of docker root directory. It was set to /data01/docker(not default value : /var/lib/docker). Is there any problem with this setting?

Comment: Did you find a solution to tell rancher new docker location? I currently think about manually add a bind-mount volume to new docker location.